# Why is probability density funciton equal to 1 between 0 and 1?

Tags: probability-distributions

I think I don't get the probability density function. At least on uniform distribution.

There are infinitely many numbers between $0$ and $1$, in probability, I understand this means that the weight it assigns to individual points must necessarily be zero. For this reason, we represent a continuous distribution with a probability density function (pdf) such that the probability of seeing a value in a certain interval equals the integral of the density function over the interval.

Then I don't get why, [in this book page 74](http://backspaces.net/temp/Ebooks/DataScienceFromScratch/Data_Science_from_Scratch.pdf), the density function for the uniform distribution is just:

```
def uniform_pdf(x):
    return 1 if x >= 0 and x < 1 else 0
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
def uniform_pdf(x):
    return x if x >= 0 and x < 1 else 0
```

Comment: Using the second distribution definition violates the nature of the uniform distribution; any two intervals $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ of *equal length* inside $[0,1]$ must receive the same probability.

Comment: With your pdf, is the probability of being below $\frac12$ equal to $\int\limits_0^{1/2} x \, dx = \frac18$ ?  Or $\int\limits_0^{1/2} 1 \, dx = \frac12$ ?

Comment: You seem to be thinking of the distribution, rather than the density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you write, " the probability of seeing a value in a certain interval equals the integral of the density function over the interval." For the uniform distribution, the probability of seeing a value in the interval $[a,b]$ ($0\le a\le b\le1$) is $b-a$, and this agrees with $\int_a^b1\,dx$, not with $\int_a^bx\,dx$.